# solve : $x_1'=3x_1-2x_2-e^{2t},x_2'=x_1+x_2$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

> Solve : \begin{align}x_1'&=3x_1-2x_2-e^{2t}\\
> x_2'&=x_1+x_2\end{align}

I believe I managed to reach for this solution for the homogeneous part $$y=c_1e^t(-\sin t+\cos t)(1,1)+c_2e^t(\sin t-\cos t) (0,1) $$

but I don't know if I am correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to solve
$\begin{pmatrix}x_1'\\x_2'\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}3 & -2 \\ 1 & 1\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}x_1\\x_2\end{pmatrix}+\begin{pmatrix}-e^{2t}\\0\end{pmatrix}$

We will follow the procedure in these [online notes](http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/DE/NonhomogeneousSystems.aspx).

The matrix $\begin{pmatrix}3 & -2 \\ 1&1\end{pmatrix}$ has eigenvalues $\begin{pmatrix}1+i\\1\end{pmatrix}$  and $\begin{pmatrix}1-i\\1\end{pmatrix}$ and respective eigenvectors $2+i$ and $2-i$.

The solution to the homogeneous part is therefore $\begin{pmatrix}x_1\\x_2\end{pmatrix}=c_1e^{(2+i)t}\begin{pmatrix}1+i\\1\end{pmatrix}+c_2e^{(2-i)t}\begin{pmatrix}1-i\\1\end{pmatrix}$.

To solve the inhomogeneous part, consider the matrix $\displaystyle X=\begin{pmatrix}(1+i)e^{(2+i)t} &(1-i)e^{(2-i)t}\\ e^{(2+i)t}&e^{(2-i)t}\end{pmatrix}$ .

The next step is to calculate $$\displaystyle \int X^{-1}\begin{pmatrix}-e^{2t}\\0\end{pmatrix}\mathrm{d}t=\int\begin{pmatrix}(1+i)e^{(4+i)t}\\ (-1+i)^{(4-i)t}\end{pmatrix}\mathrm{d}t=\begin{pmatrix}\frac{5+3i}{5}e^{(4+i)t}\\ \frac{-5+3i}{5}e^{(4-i)t}\end{pmatrix}$$.

The particular solution is then $\displaystyle X\begin{pmatrix}\frac{5+3i}{5}e^{(4+i)t}\\ \frac{-5+3i}{5}e^{(4-i)t}\end{pmatrix}$.

The solution to the system of diferential equations is the sum of the homogeneous and particular solutions.

Comment: can you substitute in terms of sin and cos?

Comment: also I am not sure why the next step is right. why you have taken the inverse matrix and integrate it?

Comment: The reason for integrating $X^{-1}g$ is explained in the variation of parameters section of the linked page.

Comment: To substitute in terms of sin and cos use $e^{it}=\cos t + i\sin t$.